# (TBS) TinyButStrong optional sub-blocks

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

Is there a way to make sub-blocks optional,  there are cases when a sub-block doesn't contain any information and I get errors. Lets say I have a block that contains people's data, like their full name, date of birth, then I have a sub-block for vehicles they own, there might be cases when they don't own one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter `bmagnet` in order to delete a block when it has no data. It works also for sub-blocks.

[Doc on parameter bmagnet](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_bmagnet)